To find CI of population proportion, why is Z value used even though we estimate unknown p from the sample?
Under suitable conditions, we have:
$$\frac{\hat{p} - p}{SE(\hat{p})} \sim N(0,1) $$
But we do not usually know $p$, so we end up estimating it by the sample, $\hat{p}_{val}$. When we now use the estimated standard error $\widehat{SE}(\hat p)$ in the LHS above, is it still true that:
$$\frac{\hat{p} - \hat{p}_{val}}{\widehat{SE}(\hat{p})} \sim N(0,1) $$
Reason why I ask is that if $p$ is unknown, should not the 95% CI be wider than obtained by using 1.96 like so:
$$ \hat{p}_{val} \pm 1.96 \widehat{SE}(\hat{p})$$
to account for the additional uncertainty surrounding the true $p$?
After all, in constructing the 95% CI for population mean, if population $\sigma$ is unknown, we estimate it using the sample standard deviation and then end up using the more variable $t$ distribution instead of the normal distribution, hence my query.

Your post is very confusing because your $\hat p_{val}$ appears to be just another name for $\hat p.$  Could you explain the distinction?

Oh sorry. I use $\hat{p}$ for the random variable, and $\hat{p}_{val}$ for one of its actual numerical realization in a particular sample. So, the latter is not a random variable, it is just some number.

That remains confusing, because the "actual numerical realization" is modeled as a random variable.

Hmm...in my (possibly wrong) way of thinking, $SE(\hat{p})$ would make sense as $\hat{p}$ is a random variable, but $SE(\hat{p}{val})$ would by syntactically wrong because there is no standard deviation or variance of a specific number. Would it help if I edited out all $\hat{p}{val}$ away from the question?

Some clarification would be welcome.  But your question likely already has a good answer.  Have you investigated our most popular posts on the topic?

I think you will find all the answers you need in this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411699/why-we-don-t-make-use-of-the-t-distribution-for-constructing-a-confidence-interv?rq=1 . The short and sweet is that while t is not mathematically correct (because $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are correlated for the binomial), it would better anyway. But there are even better "normal approximations" such as Agresti-Coull.
