# how to replicate the stata "margins, atmeans" command in R with the margins library

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, stata, marginal-model

i'm trying to replicate the output of `margins female, atmeans` in R shown here:

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/dae/using-margins-for-predicted-probabilities/

i can re-create the same setup shown on the ucla page with

```
library(foreign)
library(margins)

x <- read.dta( "https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta" )
x$honors <- as.numeric( x$honors == 'enrolled' )
```

and this code matches the **logit honors i.female read** line on ucla's page

```
this_model <- glm( honors ~ female + read , data = x , family = binomial() )
summary(this_model)
```

from here, i'm confused about how to modify

```
summary(margins(this_model))
```

so that i'm replicating the stata `atmeans` parameter.  my goal is to reproduce the output shown on the ucla page, but in R instead of stata:

```
margins female, atmeans

Adjusted predictions                              Number of obs   =        200
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Pr(honors), predict()
at           : 0.female        =        .455 (mean)
               1.female        =        .545 (mean)
               read            =       52.23 (mean)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      female |
          0  |   .1127311   .0350115     3.22   0.001     .0441097    .1813524
          1  |   .2804526   .0509114     5.51   0.000     .1806681    .3802371
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the [R `margins` library help pages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html) discusses the `atmeans` command, but it's not obvious to me how to implement this:

> atmeans: calculate marginal effects at the mean (MEMs) of a dataset rather than the default behavior of calculating average marginal effects (AMEs)
>
> Stata’s atmeans argument is not implemented in margins() for various reasons, including because it is possible to achieve the effect manually through an operation like `data$var <- mean(data$var, na.rm = TRUE)` and passing the modified data frame to `margins(x, data = data)`.

Comment: I think the quotation that you give outlines exactly the steps that you need to follow. Suppose your data lives in `data` and `var` is the variable that you're interested in. You'd replace the raw values of `var` with the average of the values of `var`. That's what the line 

`data$var <- mean(data$var, na.rm = TRUE)`

 accomplishes. Then you just supply `data` to `margins`. Can you clarify what part you're having trouble with?

Comment: hi, i'm not understanding.  could you take the minimal example i've provided and match the ucla-published numbers using R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `margin` only reports the effect.

```
> mar <-  margins(this_model, 
+                          data = x,
+                          type = "response",
+                          var = c("female"),
+                          at = list(read = mean(x$read))
+ )
> summary(mar)
       factor    read    AME     SE      z      p  lower  upper
 femalefemale 52.2300 0.1677 0.0585 2.8673 0.0041 0.0531 0.2824
```

You can see that this is sort of equivalent to the stata code, for instance $0.2804526-0.1127311 = 0.1677215 \approx 0.1677$

---

This is mentioned here

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html

> The functionality of Stata's command to produce predictive margins is
>   not ported, as this is easily obtained from the prediction package

---

So you can use the prediction function. For example:

```
newdata <- data.frame(female = c("male","female"),
                        read = rep(mean(x$read),2))
p <- predict(object = this_model,
             newdata = newdata,
             type = "response",
             se.fit = TRUE)
mult <- qnorm(0.5*(1-0.95))
out <- cbind(p$fit,
             p$se.fit,
             p$fit+p$se.fit*mult,
             p$fit-p$se.fit*mult)
rownames(out) <- levels(newdata$female)[newdata$female]
colnames(out) <- c("margin", "Std.Err", "lower 95% conf", "upper 95% conf")
```

with output

```
> out
          margin    Std.Err lower 95% conf upper 95% conf
male   0.1127310 0.03501142     0.04410991      0.1813522
female 0.2804526 0.05091129     0.18066832      0.3802369
```

In the above the confidence intervals are computed manually since the `predict` function does not do this for glm objects. I believe it is [a bit tricky](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/320809/164061) to [compute the confidence interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/358452/164061) for glm objects since the estimate of the variance (and maybe also the effective degrees of freedom?) is not straightforward. The method above, which matches the stata output uses a computation of 95% confidence intervals based on $\pm 1.96$ times the standard error and is based on a normal distribution (for the estimate of the mean/margin with known variance). This works because the data is modeled with a binomial distribution (where estimate of mean and variance are related). But it does not work in general for GLM and sometimes you should use a t-distribution which gives a slightly wider interval (or much larger interval when the sample size is small).

There is alternatively the `glm.predict` function which computes all this stuff based on a simulation (what kind of simulation I do not know).

```
> library(glm.predict)
> predicts(this_model,"F;mean",sim.count = 1000000, set.seed = 1)
       mean      lower     upper female  read
1 0.1174438 0.06010156 0.2013822   male 52.23
2 0.2832163 0.19213931 0.3900793 female 52.23
```

Comment: Sidenote... the UCLA website is using the term 'predicted probability'. To me this sounds a bit as a confusing term. It confuses me when I start to think what a 'predicted probability' could literally mean... Is it a prediction for the mean-parameter (ie probability) in a Bernouilli/binomial distributed random variable?.  It is at least *not* a prediction interval, it is a (confidence) interval expressing the error of the estimates of the mean.

Answer (score 0):

following up with info to replicate the second half of this ucla page:

```
library(foreign)

x <- read.dta( "https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta" )
x$honors <- as.numeric( x$honors == 'enrolled' )
x$female <- as.numeric( x$female == 'female' )

this_model <- glm( honors ~ female + read , data = x , family = binomial() )


newdata <- expand.grid(female = mean(x$female),
       read = seq(20,70,10))
 p <- predict(object = this_model,
     newdata = newdata,
     type = "response",
     se.fit = TRUE)
 mult <- qnorm(0.5*(1-0.95))
 out <- cbind(p$fit,
             p$se.fit,
     p$fit+p$se.fit*mult,
     p$fit-p$se.fit*mult)
rownames(out) <- seq(20,70,10)
colnames(out) <- c("margin", "Std.Err", "lower 95% conf", "upper 95% conf")
```

matches stata `margins, at(read=(20(10)70)) atmeans vsquish post` output:

```
   margin      Std.Err lower 95% conf upper 95% conf
20 0.002226388 0.001962525   -0.001620091    0.006072867
30 0.009363869 0.006100713   -0.002593308    0.021321046
40 0.038500176 0.016282790    0.006586493    0.070413859
50 0.145023969 0.031199410    0.083874250    0.206173689
60 0.418114778 0.049886309    0.320339409    0.515890147
70 0.752714028 0.067025506    0.621346451    0.884081606
```